# Application is running out postgres connections after JDK upgrade

Tags: java, postgresql, grails

I upgraded my grails application from JDK 8 to JDK 11. We have some automated tests, that ran okay in JDK8.
But now with JDK11, I get after a while this exceptions:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Is there a difference in the behavior of the Postgres connection pool in this two JDK versions? I did not change anything in the configuration for the upgrade or changed anything in the Postgres.conf.

Comment: Are you sure no other application is actually connected to the database? Check it with "select * from pg_stat_activity" looking at the column client_addr.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It is on my local developer computer, there is just my application connected to postgres.

Answer (score 2):

So the most likely explanation is that you have a resource leak.  Your application ... or your testcases (!) ... are leaking database connections.

If that is the case, the root cause is in your code.

---

A typical JDBC driver will attempt to defend itself against resource leaks by using `finalize` methods or a `Cleaner` or something like that to close `Connection` and related objects when they are found to be unreachable.  The problem is that these mechanisms only kick in *after* the GC has detected that the objects are no longer reachable.

And that is where the Java version change could come into play.  The behavior of GCs is Java version sensitive, either directly because the GCs implementations themselves change, or indirectly because things like default heap sizes, "new space" and "old space" sizing defaults, default tenuring parameters and so on can change.  As a result, it is possible that the GC will take longer to find and close `Connection` objects that have been dropped by the application.

If too many `Connection` objects are dropped, and / or the GC doesn't find them quickly enough, you end up with too many open connections, and the database backend won't let you open any more.

> Is there a difference in the behavior of the Postgres connection pool in this two JDK versions?

The connection pool relies on the GC to deal with pool connections that your application doesn't return to the pool ... in the approved fashion.  The consequences are as above.

---

The solution is to clean up your resource leaks.

The best way to do this is overhaul your codebase, and make sure that you *always* use [*try with resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to manage the `Connection` objects.